# Flask Modal not working when table is empty

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I'm trying to get this modal working. I have a simple flask web app with a SQLite database and some JavaScript code to add new rows to the table with a modal.

Everything works fine, as long as there isn't a row at the table anymore. If the table is empty, I am not able to open the modal anymore. If there is at least one row, the modal works fine and opens right.

I've uploaded the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/bq4seprt

I have tried debugging the error and get following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLButtonElement.btn.<computed>.onclick
```

at the line:

```
modal.style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to note from your code

You dont need the conditional statement `{% for row in rows %}` to create a new modal for each item you add.  With the `{% for row in rows %}` conditional you have, there is no modal class to select when the table is empty so the modal is null.

What you need to do is remove the conditional statement for your current modal, get the data from your form and  then adding the new data to you sqlite.  You have the close button to  set the modal display to none and then the modal-button to change the display to block. You are using flask so i would assume you already have the code to get data from the form and add them to your sqlite database. All you need to use javascript for is to show and hide the modal

Also for the classes that only exist once in your code, you dont need the querySelectorAll, use the querySelector instead

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, removing the {% for row in rows %} did the trick.